# Why does my Drush post_make hook not run from bash script?

Tags: drush

I have written a drush extension that runs some post_make operations.

It's all good when I run `$ drush make` normally.

I have also written a bash script, which with some arguments, perfoms also drush site-install and other file structure stuff. The problem is when I execute this script and bash runs my drush make, my extension and post_hook is not running.

I know it's more of a bash permissions/ownership thing or something, than a drush issue, but does anyone have an idea?

My extension lives in ~/.drush/extension.

I'm using drush 5.9 and this is [the actual script](https://github.com/xxronis/makedrupal/blob/master/makedrupal).

Answer (score 1):

Do you run the script as the same user that you run the `drush make` directly as?  Or do you perhaps run the script from `cron`?  Check to make sure that your $HOME environment variable is pointing to the expected directory; if $HOME is not set, then Drush will not find your commandfiles.

Comment: Thanks, $HOME var points to the correct location, also if I echo it from the script I get the correct location...what else to look for?

Comment: Does your Drush extension, or any Drush extension in the same directory, define any Drush commands?  Put `drush help commandname` in your script, and see if Drush is finding the commandfile. If you don't have any commands, just download one, e.g. `drush dl drushify`

Comment: Project drushify (7.x-1.0) downloaded to /home/<user>/.drush/drushify.Same location as my extension, I can see drushify help from that location..

Comment: Run `drush ev 'return drush_commandfile_list();'` and see if it includes your commandfile. Also, you should do these operations both from the command line and from your script, and look for any variations in behavior.

Comment: That was useful. From both ends I get the same array containing my extension from /home/<user>/.drush/<extension>, drushify, and also the core extensions from /usr/share/drush/commands. Weird stuff - I can also verify that if I  execute my drush-make from a bash alias, it will work (!) but still not working from the script :(

Comment: Okay, next run your Drush make command with the --show-invoke flag. This will cause Drush to print out all of the commandfile hooks for the make command. You must have this right if your hook is being called sometimes, I would imagine, so this is a difficult question. If your commandfile is listed in the commandfile list, then it should be called for all of the valid hooks that Drush invokes.